# X and Y are continuous random variables that are distributed jointly , and given $X\le Y$, then the following MUST occur

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> X and Y are continuous random variables that are distributed jointly and given $X\le Y$, then one of the following MUST occur:
>
> 1.) $X^2 \le Y^2$
>
> 2.) $f_X(t) \le f_Y(t)$ for all $t\in R$
>
> 3.) $f_X(t) \ge f_Y(t)$ for all $t\in R$
>
> 4.) $F_X(t) \le F_Y(t)$ for all $t\in R$
>
> 5.) $F_X(t) \ge F_Y(t)$for all $t\in R$

What exactly does the given "X and Y are jointly" distributed contribute to our understand of the situation?

And how do I disprove each option one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulation is not very clear to me. It seems that we may assume that $X,Y$ have some joint probability distribution on a space $\Omega$  and that for (almost) every $\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \leq Y(\omega)$.

Some hints:

For 1) note that we didn't say that they take positive values.

For 2,3) the pointwise marginal density of probablity (I presume this is the meaning with small f) has little to do with the information.

For 4,5) If you look at the set $\{\omega: Y(\omega)<t\}$ what happens with $X$ on that set?

Comment: Fixed the wording, tell me if that's ok.

Comment: The ambiguity has no influence on the solution (so honestly don't worry about this): You may interpret as if (1)  $X\leq Y$ a.s. or you may interpret that (2)  $X$ and $Y$ have no constraints but that you condition to the set $\Omega$ for which $X\leq Y$ (i.e. renormalizing probabilities). If $\Omega$ has positive probability it all boils down to the same in the end. Hope the hints are of use? (but I see the 'solution' has already been given away...)

Answer (score 0):

Since we are given $X\leq Y$, we have for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$,

\begin{eqnarray}
\{\omega\in \Omega:Y(w)\leq t\}\subseteq \{\omega\in \Omega:X(w)\leq t\},
\end{eqnarray}

and thus, it follows that for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\{\omega\in \Omega:Y(w)\leq t\}\right)&\leq \mathbb{P}\left(\{\omega\in \Omega:X(w)\leq t\}\right)\\\Rightarrow F_{Y}(t)&\leq F_{X}(t).
\end{align}